# Error : cannot use stripe token more than once

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a monthly subscription plan using the stripe API, but I have an error message saying

> Cannot use stripe token more than once

And when I try to remove `'source'  => $token` I have this error :

> The customer must have an active payment source attached.

Here's my code :

```
require_once('stripe/config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
'email' => $email,
'source'  => $token,
]);


\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

$product = \Stripe\Product::create([
'name' => 'Abonnement Simple',
'type' => 'service', 
]);


$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
"customer" => $customer->id,
"plan" => "simpleNoEngagement"
));
```

Comment: you already set API key somewhere, the fact that you already created customer means Stripe has been initialized, otherwise you cannot create customer.

Comment: The token could only be used once in Stripe. If you want to reuse it, you will have to save the token into Customer like what you've done in creating Customer with token. After that, you could simple charge or create subscriptions on the customer, the saved card will be used by default. Here I think the problem is your subscription create signature, you should follow this API doc at https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create. You will need to put plan inside an items array.

Answer (score 1):

token is required only for creating new customer. Once customer is created, you do not need to send token again. You need to grab customerId in that case.